# How did Allies calculate risk of detection for acting upon intercepted ENIGMA transmissions

Tags: probability

We read that once the ENIGMA was broken, the Allied mathematicians carefully calculated the probability of Axis detecting it was broken prior to acting upon intelligence received through intercepted Enigma transmissions.

If we recall correctly, it understandably weighed heavily upon the team if, for example they discovered a ship would be attacked but preventing the attack would carry too great a risk of revealing the broken cipher.

This seems remarkably interesting, yet incredibly challenging. How would one go about building a probabilistic model for such complex scenarios?

Comment: I doubt they had a model. Probably more like a combination of heuristics and political decision making. If you have a source for the claim that it was “calculated”, please add it.

Comment: I also doubt there was a formal model, but I think this question (look at the only sentence with a question mark at the end) remains valid in more generality than the enigma. This could spawn some interesting posts about decision theory.